# Help with an analysis problem involving isomorphisms and volumes.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, geometry

I would like some help solving the following problem:

Let $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a class $C^{1}$ function. Suppose that for some $a \in U$ the derivative of $f$ in $a$ is an isomorphism. Prove that $$ \lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{Vol \left( f \left( B\left[ a; r\right] \right) \right)}{Vol \left( B\left[ a; r\right] \right)} = \left| \det f^{\prime} \left( a \right) \right|,$$ where $Vol$ means *volume* and $B\left[ a; r\right] = \{ u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}: \| u-a \| \leq r \}$ is the closed ball.

So far, I only know that the right side of the equation is never zero, and was thinking that the hypothesis in this problem are the same as the Inverse Function Theorem. However I don't know if it is really of use here since it gives a result about $f \left(U\right)$ and the problem involves $f \left( B\left[ a; r\right] \right).$

I need some hints to get moving; I **do not want** the full solution of the problem,  since this is an exam-type exercise and I need to learn how to solve it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Prove $|\det(f'(x))|$ is a continuous function.
2. Prove that for any continuous function $g(x)$ you have that $$g(x_0) = \frac{1}{\operatorname{Vol}(B[x_0;r])} \int_{B[x_0;r]} g(x) \, dx.$$
3. Use (1) in (2) and change of variables.

If you need more help just say.